# Displaying the image does not work

Tags: ros, python, 2d-image, ros-kinetic, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am trying to make a simple program that will show me what the robot see. I want to learn how to use OpenCV.

I am using a real TurtleBot3 burger. It has a camera which give me the image in `Compressed` format. Before starting my program I launched this node:

```
<node name="republish" type="republish" pkg="image_transport" output="screen" args="compressed in:=/compressed_image out:=/raw_image" />
```

And now I have in `/raw_image` the image in `Image` format. But my program still is no working.

Below is my code. It stuck when I want to transform the image in OpenCv format.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image


class MyCamera:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.bridge_object = CvBridge()
        self.image = Image()
        rospy.on_shutdown(self.shutdownhook)
        
    def show_img(self):
        self.image = rospy.wait_for_message('raw_image', Image)
        cv_image = self.bridge_object.imgmsg_to_cv2(self.image, desired_encoding="bgr8")
        cv2.imshow('image', cv_image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        
    
    def shutdownhook(self):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    

def run():
    rospy.init_node('my_camera_node')
    obj = MyCamera()
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        obj.show_img()
        rospy.sleep(1)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338087/displaying-the-image-does-not-work/) by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem... I didn't set the good topic where to subscribe.

---

Originally posted by [oovidiustr](https://answers.ros.org/users/45777/oovidiustr/) with karma: 41 on 2019-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0